# What data type to be used for description of an object?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

A table has a field of description in sql server. If I take varchar then its maximum limit is 8000 characters but a description can be larger than that. I am using this field for a job description which are normally lengthy .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `VARCHAR(MAX)`. It can store more than 8k chars. Actually it can store up to 2GB

**varchar [ ( n | max ) ]**

*Variable-length, non-Unicode string data. `n` defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 8,000. **`MAX` indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB)**. The storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes. The ISO synonyms for varchar are char varying or character varying.*

Read more at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx

Please note, that the `TEXT` and `NTEXT` types can store nearly the same amount of data, but they are obsolete and you can do less operations on them. **Use `VARCHAR(MAX)` and `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead of `TEXT` and `NTEXT`.**

Answer (score 4):

A [`varchar(max)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms176089.aspx) has no (effective) limit. Use that.

Comment: Is `varchar(max)` is better than `ntext`/`text`?

Comment: Please somebody Upvote the ques. My repo is going down.

Answer (score -1):

You can use
`varchar(max) or Text` data type.

Comment: TEXT is deprecated, use VARCHAR(MAX) instead!